# Why can't typescript infer class's method return type as generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is working correctly:

```js
abstract class X<T extends Record<PropertyKey, any> > {
  abstract index(): T
}

class Y extends X<{name:string}> {
  index() {
    return {name:"Test"}
  }
}
```

But this causes an error:

```js
abstract class X<T extends Record<PropertyKey, any> > {
  abstract index(): T
}

class Y extends X {
  index():{name:string} {
    return {name:"Test"}
  }
}
```

The error:

> Generic type 'X' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

This might not be a problem but what if the class has more generic.
Like this I need to retype `EmptyObject` for the generic even though it's the default.

```js
type EmptyObject = Record<PropertyKey, never>

abstract class X<E extends Record<PropertyKey, any> = EmptyObject, T extends Record<PropertyKey, any> = EmptyObject> {
  abstract index(data: E): T
}

// I want to just do "extends X" and make typescript infer the rest
class Y extends X<EmptyObject, {name:string}> {
  index(data: EmptyObject): {name:string} {
    return {name:"Test"}
  }
}
```

Comment: So your question is "why can't TS infer..." from the title? It's because such a feature was never implemented. If you want to see this happen you can upvote and comment on [ms/TS#39180](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39180) but it probably won't happen anytime soon or ever. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Well yes, if it's not feature :(... Also you are very active :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot currently infer a class's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument from its implementation. It's a missing feature, requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#39180](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39180). It's listed as "awaiting more feedback", meaning that they want to see a lot of community engagement and support for the feature before they consider implementing it.  It's been around for a long time and there has been very little engagement, so I'd say it's quite unlikely for it ever to appear in the language. You could give it a  and explain your use case, but it's probably not going to change anything.

Type inference generally does not work that way in TypeScript. Generic type arguments are only inferred when you call a generic function. They are not inferred contextually.  For the foreseeable future, you will need to manually specify the generic type arguments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What if you modified the second code block to:

```js
abstract class X<T = Record<PropertyKey, any> > {
  abstract index(): T
}

class Y extends X {
  index():{name:string} {
    return {name:"Test"}
  }
}
```

I went straight to the third block, with some tinkering around the types, I got to this:

```js
type BaseObjectType = Record<PropertyKey, any>

abstract class X<E = BaseObjectType> {
  abstract index(data: E): E;
}

class Y<T extends BaseObjectType> extends X<T> {
  index(data: T):T {
    return {
      ...data,
      name: "Test",
    };
  }
}
```

Or if you wanted to maintain the `BaseObjectType`, you could do either

```js
type BaseObjectType = Record<PropertyKey, any>
```

or

```js
type BaseObjectType = Record<PropertyKey, any> & { name: "Test" };
```

And combine it with just returning the `name` property from `index`

```js
abstract class X<E = BaseObjectType> {
  abstract index(data: E): E;
}

class Y<T extends BaseObjectType> extends X<T> {
  index(data: T): BaseObjectType {
    return {
      name: "Test",
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The third snippet is like a base class for a function that receive something and output something different, so the type can be different. Also the type can be different for each implementation so i can't just hard code it in the type. EmptyObject is for typing empty object because if i use {} it won't work.